# Swift How can I convert String from class into @State String variable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I convert this variable from my class into the `@State` variable in my View? I am getting an exception right now:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Binding' to type 'String'

Inside my View:

```
 struct ContentView: View {

    //Error private members
    @State var alert = false
    @State var error = ""

    @EnvironmentObject var manager: HttpAuth

    func verify(){
    //Cannot assign value of type Binding<String> to type String
     self.error = $manager.error

   }
}
```

Inside my `HttpAuth` class

```
    class HttpAuth: ObservableObject{
    
        //Error private members
        var alert = false
        var error: String = ""
    
        ..
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need binding here, `@State` is a property wrapper, so assign like property

```
func verify(){
   self.error = manager.error   // no $
}
```

**Note:** actually you can use `manager.error` directly, w/o remapping it to provide state, just make it `@Published`

```
class HttpAuth: ObservableObject{

    //Error private members
    var alert = false
    @Published var error: String = ""
```

the only caution(!) you must modify this published `error` *only* on main queue, and then all usage inside View will be updated automatically.